# .NET Maui Mac: The target platform identifier android was not recognized

Tags: c#, .net, macos, maui

Because Maui has so many issues and will only display a black screen when using an iOS Simulator on Windows through 'Pair to Mac', all I want to do is build and test my code directly on my mac to see if that will change anything. Builds fine on windows but on the mac it will not, and I get this error: 'NuGet packages need to be restored before building.'

When I right click on the NuGet folder and click restore, it gives me another error: 'error NETSDK1139: The target platform identifier android was not recognized. Unable to create package spec for project.'

I have reinstalled all of the workloads but the issue persists and I have no idea where to go from here.

I am not able to install any NuGet packages for the Maui project whatsoever.

Comment: Not sure what is messed up; probably easiest to make a new Maui project in VS Mac. Verify you can build & run the new project. Then add your source files to it.

Comment: Did you try to reinstall the visual studio for the mac or create a new project to test?

Comment: I created a new Maui project and then imported all of the files over and everything worked fine. I still do not know what the issue is with the original project.